# Why are there different encoding types?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

This is a noob question, but I wanna know why there are different encoding types and what are their differences (ie. ASCII, utf-8 and 16, base64, etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reasons are many I believe but the main point is: "How many characters you need to display (encode)?" If you live in US for example, you could go pretty far with ASCII. But in many counties we need characters like ä, å, ü etc. (If SO was ASCII only or you try to read this text as ASCII encoded text, you'd see some weird characters in the places of ä, å and ü.) Think also the China, Japan, Thailand and other "exotic" countires. Those weird figures on photos you may have seen around the world just might be letters, not pretty pictures.

As for the differences between different encoding types you need to see their specification. Here's something for UTF-8.

- http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html
- http://www.utf-8.com/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Compared_to_other_multi-byte_encodings

I'm not familiar with UTF-16. Here's some information about the differences.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_plane

Base64 is used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs to be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data. If you've ever made somesort of email system with PHP, you've probably encountered Base64.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64
- http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

Is short: To support computer program's user interface localizations to many different languages. (Programming languages still mainly consist of characters found in ASCII encoding, althought it's possible for example in Java to use UTF-8 encoding in variable names, and the source code file is usually stored as something else than ASCII encoded text, for example UTF-8 encoding.)

In short vol.2: Always when different people are trying to solve some problem from a specific point of view (or even without a point of view if it's even possible), results may be quite different. Quote from Joel's unicode article (link below): "Because bytes have room for up to eight bits, lots of people got to thinking, "gosh, we can use the codes 128-255 for our own purposes." The trouble was, lots of people had this idea at the same time, and they had their own ideas of what should go where in the space from 128 to 255."

Thanks to Joachim and tchrist for all the info and discussion. Here's two articles I just read. (Both links are on the page I linked to earlier.) I'd forgotten most of the stuff from Joel's article since I last read it a few years back. Good introduction to the subject I hope. Mark Davis goes a little deeper.

- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
- http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/forms_of_unicode/

Comment: Sorry, this answer simply contains to many incorrect parts: UTF-16 can't represent any more characters than UTF-8, because both of them can represent **all** Unicode characters. ASCII is rarely ever used for  Java source code, UTF-8 or some ISO-8859-* variant are more common (even if it often doesn't make a difference, because the code only contains ASCII-encodable characters). It should also be noted that Base64 is **not** a character encoding at all! It's a way to represent binary data in a textual form.

Comment: @Joachim Thank you for your input. I edited my answer. Not sure how to interpret the Java portion of your comment. I meant (and thought that I wrote) that the source code is ASCII (reserved words, funtion names, language construct), but the file itself is something else. For example my PHP files are encoded in UTF-8 but the HTML tags and PHP code consists of ASCII characters. This doesn't include i.e. the echoed strings and other text visible to the end user (which is why I need to use UTF-8 in the first place). Please comment for further improvemens.

Comment: Java restricts the characters and symbols used in its language specification to those representable in ASCII. But that doesn't mean that Java source code is automatically ASCII text. It only means that it *can* be  encoded in ASCII.

Comment: @Joachim Yes I understand that. Ihoped that my PHP example made it clear. I just don't understand why we aren't on a same page. I've seen how variable names in Java can be something else than ASCII characters. I'll edit my answer again or remove the whole Java note from it if it makes you happy. Is it correct to say: "the programming language is constructed of ASCII reprecentable characters, but the file encoding can be something else"?

Comment: I simply don't like the (slightly sloppy) use of the term ASCII to refer to "text restricted to ASCII-encodable characters". ASCII, as a text encoding, has become *incredibly* unimportant by now, but is *still* quoted a lot, for no real reason except as an excuse not to learn what the encodings are that are *actually* in use today.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks again. Hopefully I edited all the sloppiness away. Is this enough to make the -1 go away or should I just give up trying? I must admit that your knoweledge in this area is far superior to mine, but I hope the last of the incorrecness's are edited out from my post.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You claim that Java resticts characters and symbols used in its language specification to those reprensentable in ASCII. You are correct, but it is easy to misread what you have written as saying something that is incorrect. For example, although ***the spec*** for Java identifiers or literals is indeed in ASCII, those literals can contain arbitrary Unicode code points, and Java identifiers can contain Unicode identifier characters (IDS, IDC) supplemented with currency symbols (GC=Sc). Java also has its own set of “default ignorables” that conflicts with those of Unicode proper.

Answer (score 11):

The real reason why there are so many variants is that [the Unicode consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium) came along too late.

In The Beginning memory and storage was expensive and using more than 8 (or sometimes only 7) bit of memory to store a single character was considered excessive. Thus pretty much all text was stored using 7 or 8 bit per character. Clearly, 8 bit are not enough memory to represent the characters of **all** human languages. It's barely enough to represent *most* characters used in *a single language* (and for some languages even that's not possible). Therefore many different character encodings where designed to allow different languages (English, German, Greek, Russian, ...) to encode *their* texts in 8 bits per characters. After all a single text file (and usually even a single computer system) will only ever used in a single language, right?

This led to a situation where there was no single agreed-upon mapping of characters to numbers of any kind. Many different, incompatible solutions where produced and no real central control existed. Some computer systems used [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), others used [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (or more precisely: one of the many variations of EBCDIC), [ISO-8859-*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) (or one of its many derivatives) or any of a big list of encodings that are hardly heard about now.

Finally, the Unicode Consortium stepped up to the task to produce that single mapping (together with **lots** of auxiliary data that's useful but outside of the bounds of this answer).

When the Unicode consortium finally produced a *fairly* comprehensive list of characters that a computer might represent (together with a number of encoding schemes to encode them to binary data, depending on your concrete needs), the other character encoding schemes were already widely used. This slowed down the adoption of Unicode and its encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16) considerably.

These days, if you want to represent text, your best bet is to use one of the few encodings that can represent all Unicode characters. UTF-8 and UTF-16 together should suffice for 99% of all use cases, UTF-32 covers almost all the others. And just to be clear: all the UTF-* encodings can encode all valid Unicode characters. But due to the fact that UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable-width encodings, they might not be ideal for all use cases. Unless you need to be able to interact with a legacy system that *can't* handle those encodings, there is rarely a reason to choose anything else these days.

Comment: This is incorrect.  All three of UTF-{8,16,32} can represent precisely 100.00% of all legal Unicode scalar values. What UTF-16 cannot represent is the surrogates, which are not legal Unicode scalar values. The UTF-{8,32} algorithms can represent said values, but those are explicitly forbidden from occurrring in a conformant stream in either of those encodings. This guarantees all legal code points can be freely interchanged in any of UTF-{8,16,32}.

Comment: @tchrist: I didn't mean to say that UTF-32 can somehow represent more characters, but that in some use cases its fixed-width properties are necessary (for example if you absolutely need *O(1) indexing* into a Unicode string). In those cases UTF-32 is a good solution, where UTF-8 and UTF-16 would not suffice.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is to be able to show more characters. When the internet was in it's infancy, noone really planned ahead thinking that one day there would be people using it from all countries and all languages around the world. So a small character set was good enough. Gradually it was revealed to be limited and English-centric, thus the demand for bigger character sets.

Comment: ahhh, just to support the characters from other languages, thanks

Comment: I would say "computer usage" instead of "internet". People want to use computer programs (Word, Photoshop, Thunderbird, whatever) in their native language. I edited my answer (once more) to stress localization point.

Comment: @Coola What you have written is completely wrong. **Unicode is about much much more than “non-English” characters.** It includes many specialist characters used by typesetters and proofreaders, mathematicians and physicists, linguists and lexicographers — even in 100% English-language text.